# Capture arbitrary groups of items

Tags: regex

I have a comma-separated keys + values like this:

```
Field1=33,Field2=44
```

The fields can be in an arbitrary order so it also can be something like this:

```
Field2=44,Field1=33
```

I want to get a dictionary of key-values using only one regex which would ignore the order of fields.

The simplest solution is below:

```
Field1=(?<Field1>\d*),Field2=(?<Field2>\d*)
```

But, this doesn't work for the second case were Field2 preeceds Field1.

Is there a way to achieve this without using doing extra work in code?

I don't think that regex supports this but I'm a pretty basic regex user. I'm using .net regex flavor.

Comment: `Field\d+=\d+` use this

Comment: What language are you using? You should be able to do it using lookaheads.

Comment: In general, it makes sense to use two regex method calls here.

Answer (score 0):

If you language/tool understand lookahead, you can use:

```
(?=.*(Field1=(?<field1>\d+)))(?=.*(Field2=(?<field2>\d+)))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h3v6FY/1)